# "Failed to delete the item from the trash"

Tags: trash

I was trying to delete some files of my pendrive (moving them to trash) and when i wanted to delete them permanently, an error ("Failed to delete the item from the trash") appeared. I tried to delete

```
home/myuser/.local/share/Trash/files/
```

but it didn't exist. I even installed the image again, and again, but it wont stop appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you delete something from a pendrive in linux it actually isnt deleted. its moved to a hidden folder called ".trash" you can manually delete this from the drive. but it is hidden.

Comment: A folder called .Trash-1000?

Comment: Do you mean the .Trash-1000 folder?

Comment: @Ciro yes i do.

Comment: I cant delete .Trash-1000, it says "read-only file system"

Comment: Ah ... forget about it, i already format the pendrive.

Comment: The files inside the folder were corrupted, I do not know why.